# Page transitions using Phonegap, Zepto and Backbone

Tags: jquery, cordova, backbone.js, transition, zepto

I'm developing a mobile app using Zepto,Backbone and Phonegap. I have beeen struggling to achieve page transitions. 
I've tried this library 
(https://github.com/dgileadi/zepto-page-transitions/tree/master/example). 
I cannot get it to work because it listens to the hashchange event to trigger the transition, but the Backbone router also listens to the same event, generating a conflict.
Is there a way around this issue? Is ther some other library to make transitions using Zepto and Backbone???

EDIT:

```
<div id="one" data-role="page">
        <a transition="slide" href="#two">Spin to local page two</a>
    </div>
    <div id="two" data-role="page" data-title="Page Two">
    </div>
```

When I tap on the link "Spin to local page two" the Backbone router looks for a "two" route on my app. Instead  the library I'm using for transitions should transition to the "two" div:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e) {
                var target = (action && action.element) || $(document.body);
                if (!ignoreHash[window.location.hash]) {
                    var to = window.location.hash;
 ... 
 }
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the cause or the result of the *conflict*? Both plugins listening to the hashchange event doesn't necessarily means a problem.

Comment: Check this out http://jsbin.com/amajat/10/. I created that for someone else a while back. See if you can leverage that. I have used only webkit vendor prefixes in the CSS.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out...I've been looking around for a while to switch from jQuery Mobile to another framework.  Trying to find everything I need to replace it.  Found this on GitHub for page transitions but haven't tried it yet:

[Zepto Page Transitions](https://github.com/dgileadi/zepto-page-transitions)

Let me know if you get it to work!

ps...Also are you able to prefetch pages?  I found [this](http://www.prefetchjs.de/blog.html) but it's very badly documented.  If there's an alternative, I'd be happy to hear about it.